# Capture information of system-call

Tags: logs, kvm, system-calls

I have a QEMU-KVM hypervisor (ubuntu) with several VMs.
What I want to do is capture all information of VMs system call to hypervisor (without any intervention to VM whatsoever) in real time within a log file.  I also want the information captured can be associated to which VM the system-call came from.

Is it possible?
If I want to write a program (in C or python) to do so, can anybody show resources on internet?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you want to use such information, but to capture all system calls done by vm you should run vm like:

```
strace kvm ....
```

Other possibility is to use systemtap.

Comment: I'm trying to use the info for machine learning input.  Recently been looking into VMI, but it seems for vmi to work i still need to tamper into it.
Thank you, i will look those two you mention.

Comment: “System calls” in the question is a misnomer, the question is asking about hypervisor calls, which are not system calls of the host OS.

Comment: Could you please explain/point to some additional information about "hypervisor calls"? What it is?